# Creating custom form input in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm creating my own form builder in angular.
I have html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <my-input-field
            [field]="{type:'text'}"
            [formControlName]="'first'"></my-input-field>
</form>
```

I don't know how to in `MyInputFieldComponent` fetch parent's `formGroup` (I don't want to pass it as extra property. Less boilerplate is better).
I can fetch `parentElement` itself, but how to get parent `component` to get it's `formGroup` ?

```
constructor(protected elementRef: ElementRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Why would you want to do that? Get the value of the formgroup? Why not pass the name as an @input itself? What's stopping you and what's the usecase/need?

Comment: Without that I would have to give extra attribute in all `my-input-field`. It's redundant in my opinion. `formControlName` directive knows if parent component has `formGroup` so it has to be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo don't need to inject the parent component for this, in this case the best option is implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface.

https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

You can see how to do it here: 
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

`ControlValueAccessor` is the interface to create custom form fields in Angular, if you implement it in your component `@angular/forms` can use it as a html native input, accessing the values with `ngModel` or `formControlName`

Comment: I could use that aproach. Thanks